# how to stop locust when specific number of users are spawned with -i command line option?

Tags: locust

```py
from locust import SequentialTaskSet, HttpUser, constant, task
import locust_plugins

class MySeqTask(SequentialTaskSet):
    
    @task
    def get_status(self):
        self.client.get("/200")
        print("Status of 200")

    @task
    def get_100_status(self):
        self.client.get("/100")
        print("Status of 100")

class MyLoadTest(HttpUser):

    host = "https://http.cat"
    tasks = [MySeqTask]
    wait_time = constant(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Examples for locust-plugins command line options can be found here:

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/cmd_line_examples.sh

```
locust -u 5 -t 60 --headless -i 10
# Stop locust after 10 task iterations (this is an upper bound, so you can be sure no more than 10 of iterations will be done)
# Note that in a distributed run the parameter needs to be set on the workers, it is (currently) not distributed from master to worker.
```

You will run your locust file the same way as normal but add `-i` to each worker you run. It sounds to me like since it's per worker, you'll need to pre-calculate how many you want each worker to run. So if you have 10 workers and you want to stop after a total of 10000 task iterations, you'd probably do `-i 1000` on each worker.